# Conditional format of cell with different data types in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add a fill color to a table that I created in SSRS. The data looks like the table as follows:

[image: Shows the format of the table]

The task is whenever the value is over 7, then color the cell green, when the value is less than 7 then orange and if the value is below zero then the due time changes to a sentence as shown with ID 2 and is to be colored red.

I have achieved coloring the cells when greater than or less than 7 using the if statement on the Due(Mins) field value however, it fails to color the cell red when less than 0. I have used switch, instr functions, but haven't had any luck.

Can emphasize more. Appreciate the help.

Cheers,
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!Due.Value.ToString.Contains("OverDue"), "Red",
    VAL(Fields!Due.Value) > 7, "Green",
    True, "Orange"
    )
```

Switch will stop when it hits the first expression that evaluates to `True`

So...

First we test if the value contains overdue and set red

Then we test if the value is greater than 7 and set the result to Green

The `True` at the end acts like an `else`

Comment: Spot on!! Thanks, Alan!